Getting Warning while uploading Flutter app on App store
I am getting this warning when I try to update my app [Flutter App] on appStore. xCode is showing Build is uploaded to Apple. But I am not able to see on Textflight.
Steps
The archive did not include a dSYM for the HyphenateChat.framework with the UUIDs [XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX]. Ensure that the archive's dSYM folder includes a DWARF file for HyphenateChat.framework with the expected UUIDs.
I am using Agora chat SDK and Agora Chat UI SDK.
Here is the Screenshot of the warning.

I have prepared the build using Product in Xcode menu and then selecting Archive.
after then selecting Testflight in popup window.

To solve this problem you just need to update the HyphenateChat.framework version

Hello @AvtarSingh
I am not using HyphenateChat directly instead I am using Agora Chat SDK. Do I need to update the agora chat sdk. FYI I have tried with
This version: agora_chat_sdk: ^1.2.0
and
This version: agora_chat_sdk: ^1.3.0-beta.1
but getting warning in both versions.

Since it's just a warning and doesn't affect functionality after the Xcode 16 upgrade, you can safely ignore it.

You can try the following steps:

Open the HyphenateChat.xcframework/ios-arm64 directory

create a new dSYMs folder, and
download the file from this link.
After extracting the downloaded file, move it to the newly created
directory.


Then, archive the app again, and the warning will disappear.
